# How can I call the array from the tween function to optimize my code

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a `handleKeyDown` function and onpress it executes a tween function. In this code I am tweening multi objects in an array like this :

```
function handleKeyDown(e) {
    if (!e) {
        var e = window.event;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == '1'.charCodeAt(0)) {
        var imagearray = [ChickenMale3Container, ChickenMale2Container, ChickenMaleContainer];
        imagearray.forEach(function (element) {
            rotateanscleElement(element);
        });
    }

    function rotateanscleElement(element) {
        createjs.Tween.get(element, {
            loop: false
        })
        .to({
            regY: element.height / 2,
            regX: element.width / 2,
            x: element.x + 138,
            y: element.y + 133,
            rotation: 0
        }, 1)
        .to({
            scaleX: 0.7,
            scaleY: 0.7
        }, 1000, createjs.Ease.bounceOut)
        .to({
            regY: element.height / 2,
            regX: element.width / 2,
            rotation: 360
        }, 1000)
        .to({
            scaleX: 1,
            scaleY: 1
        }, 500, createjs.Ease.bounceOut)
        .to({
            regY: 0,
            regX: 0,
            x: element.x,
            y: element.y,
            rotation: 0
        }, 1)
    }
```

What I want is to put the array and the `forEach` function in the tween function and not in the `if` condition. How can I make it for more code optimization?

Comment: I have highlighted inline code elements, improved code block formatting, corrected a few grammar and capitalization mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.keyCode=='6'.charCodeAt(0)) {

    multirotateanscleElement();
    }

function multirotateanscleElement(element) {
var imagearray = [ChickenMale3Container,ChickenMale2Container,ChickenMaleContainer];
imagearray.forEach(function(element) {
createjs.Tween.get(element, {loop: false})

    .to({regY:element.height/2, regX:element.width/2,x:element.x+138,y:element.y+133,rotation: 0}, 0)
    .to({scaleX: 0.7, scaleY: 0.7},500, createjs.Ease.bounceOut)
    .to({regY:element.height/2, regX:element.width/2,rotation:360}, 500)
    .to({scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1}, 500, createjs.Ease.bounceOut)
    .to({regY:0, regX:0,x:element.x,y:element.y,rotation: 0}, 0)
    .to({regY:element.height/2, regX:element.width/2,x:element.x+138,y:element.y+133,rotation: 360}, 0)
    .to({scaleX: 0.7, scaleY: 0.7},500, createjs.Ease.bounceOut)
    .to({regY:element.height/2, regX:element.width/2,rotation:0}, 500)
    .to({scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1}, 500, createjs.Ease.bounceOut)
    .to({regY:0, regX:0,x:element.x,y:element.y,rotation: 0}, 0)

 });
```